# LibGDX app cannot load TTF fonts due to "invalid padding"

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development, truetype

I am new to LibGDX and trying to make a very simple game. But I soon ran into an issue when using BitmapFont. In my Game class, I load a BitmapFont like so:

```
private SpriteBatch batch;
private BitmapFont font;
    
@Override
public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/PlaypenSans-ExtraLight.ttf"));
    this.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));
}
```

The TTF file was downloaded from Google Fonts. The result was the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading font file: fonts/PlaypenSans-ExtraLight.ttf
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.load(BitmapFont.java:717)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.<init>(BitmapFont.java:485)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.<init>(BitmapFont.java:116)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.<init>(BitmapFont.java:109)
        at com.ssage.pong.Pong.create(Pong.java:18)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Window.initializeListener(Lwjgl3Window.java:416)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Window.update(Lwjgl3Window.java:366)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application.loop(Lwjgl3Application.java:192)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application.<init>(Lwjgl3Application.java:166)
        at com.ssage.pong.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:16)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Invalid padding.
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.load(BitmapFont.java:500)
```

I got the same error with other TTF files.

Using BitmapFont with the default constructor (so the default font) does work. I can't find anything about the "invalid padding error" online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `BitmapFont` is a class that wraps a bitmap-font, which is a text document describing where in a image each character is located (for example [the default.fnt file from libGDX](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-tools/assets/default.fnt)), it does not load **TTF** files.

If you want to use **TTF** files in your project, you should enable the *freetype* extension (you can pick it when you create your **libGDX** project), and then use the `FreeTypeFontGenerator` to generate a `BitmapFont` on the fly.

The **libGDX** [freetype](https://libgdx.com/wiki/extensions/gdx-freetype) page has some good examples on how to do this, but essentially you

1. Create a `FreeTypeFontGenerator` passing the **TTF** file as a constructor argument.
2. Create a `FreeTypeFontParameter` object and set things like size on it.
3. Call `generateFont` on the `FreeTypeFontGenerate` object passing in the parameters, this will return a `BitmapFont`.
4. Dispose the FreeTypeFontGenerator`.